# Java Pattern Matcher not working with caching Matcher Objects e.g Redis Cache

Tags: java

I have stored Compiled Matcher Pattern object in cache (e.g redis). Like

```
final Map<String, Set<Matcher>> matchersMap = new HashMap<>();
.....
Pattern.compile(patternString).matcher("")
..........
redisCache.put("patterns", matchersMap.get("patterns"));
```

In my application, I tried use those cache patterns like

```
for( Matcher m : redisCache.get("patterns")) {
    if(m.reset(pathToTest).matches()) {
   //Success
  }
}
```

I got null pointer in m.reset(pathToTest).matches() method when i look at jdk code i see matchRoot getting null.
JDK Code

```
 boolean match(int from, int anchor) {
       ...
        boolean result = parentPattern.matchRoot.match(this, from, text); // matchRoot gets null
     .....
        return result;
    }
```

Caching of patterns (Matchers object) perform by other application using redis cache. To use those patterns there is other application. All component running locally. How can I resolve this error ?

Comment: Why are you caching the matchers? Those need to be reconstructed or reset for each input anyway and are not threadsafe, i.e. should not be shared. I'm also not sure it would make sense to cache the patterns in Redis as well. Why don't you recompile the pattern strings in your applications and cache them in memory?

Comment: Compile patterns everytime has performance issue. The reason why I haven't stored in memory because cache populated from db which gets change.

Comment: Sure, you wouldn't want to recompile the patterns every time you need them but you can't cache the patterns in their compiled state, at least not without hassle. If you have a look at `Pattern` you'll see that `matchRoot` and even `compiled` are transient so serialization will not pick them up. Thus if you cache a `Pattern` and then call `matcher(input)` as you should do the pattern will need to be recompiled anyway.

Comment: So this will not work. I need to compile pattern in application itself. Correct?

Comment: Well, you could try to cache the `Pattern` instances and make handling somewhat easier (assuming the map keys are not the patterns but some names) but in essence yes: you'd need to recompile the patterns in each application. Calling `matcher(input)` on a `Pattern` that needs to be recompiled should work as well as this will cause a recompile first.